# How to get the stream key for twitch.tv

Tags: stream, key, twitch

I write an app for broadcasting to `twitch.tv` using `C++`. For that `streaming` I need to know the user stream key, usually an user gets that key from the page,

http://www.twitch.tv/user_name/dashboard/streamkey

But I would like get it via my app by using the user name/password.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

You will get it here (change "yourtwitch" by your twitch nickname")

http://www.twitch.tv/yourtwitch/dashboard/streamkey

The link simply moved. You can get this link on the main page of twitch.tv, click on your name then "Dashboard".

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 6):

This may be an old thread but I came across it and figured that I would give a final answer.

The twitch api is json based and to recieve your stream key you need to authorize your app for use with the api. You do so under the connections tab within your profile on twitch.tv itself.. Down the bottom of said tab there is "register your app" or something similar. Register it and you'll get a client-id header for your get requests.

Now you need to attach your Oauthv2 key to your headers or as a param during the query to the following get request.

> curl -H 'Accept: application/vnd.twitchtv.v3+json' -H 'Authorization: OAuth ' \
>   -X GET https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/channel

[documentataion here](https://github.com/justintv/Twitch-API/blob/master/v3_resources/channels.md#get-channel)

As you can see in the documentation above, if you've done these two things, your stream key will be made available to you.

As I said - Sorry for the bump but some people do find it hard to read the twitch* api.

Hope that helps somebody in the future.

Comment: By doing that you're eventually going to invite anyone to abuse your client ID for their purposes. The client ID is intended to be used when deploying a solution where the code remains under your control (e.g. a web service). It is not to be used if you're publishing an application.

Answer (score 0):

You may obtain the stream key via the API:
https://github.com/justintv/twitch-api

Comment: sorry, but I don't see how to do it there

Answer (score 0):

As of January 2018 the url is https://www.twitch.tv/username/dashboard/settings/streamkey